# create API to return plot created in matplotlib

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, matplotlib, aws-lambda

I have a client UI which invokes a Python API (in AWS Lambda) that returns a basic calculation. I wanted to extend the functionality so that I could achieve the following:
1. On the client side upload data via an excel spreadsheet
2. Send over that data to that Python API (AWS Lambda)
3. In the Lambda API I work on the data using numpy, Scikit and plot a graph using matplotlib
4. Send back the plot as an image file
5. Render the image on the client UI

I am not sure as to how to bundle and pass the data to the Python API and how to send back a plot object to the client UI

Any help in formulating an architecture is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Without having any experience with matplotlib - my suggestion for sending files to/from AWS Lambda is to do one of:

1. Pass the content of the file as the payload of the lambda (base64 encoded). Max payload size is 6MB. (If you want, add an API Gateway that will trigger the lambda and use a POST request).
2. The client puts the file on S3, triggers the lambda while passing the path of the input file, then the lambda writes the output file and sends its path in the response. On the client UI, you can use the [S3 REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectOps.html) directly to work with S3 (or any SDK).